# Reading json stream without blocking

Tags: java, jackson, nonblocking

I want to be able to read stream (from a socket) of json messages using Jackson (2).

There are ways to pass a Reader as the source, such as doing:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
MyObject obj = mapper.readValue(aReader, MyObject.class);
```

but that will block until the entire json message has arrived and I want to avoid that.

Is there a way to have a buffer to which I can keep adding bytes with the ability to ask if the buffer contains a full json representation of a specific class?
Something like:

```
JsonBuffer buffer = new JsonBuffer(MyObject.class);
...
buffer.add(readBytes);
if (buffer.hasObject()) {
    MyObject obj = buffer.readObject();
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Jackson supports non-blocking JSON stream parsing [as of 2.9](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core/issues/57). You can find an example about how to use it in Spring Framework 5 [Jackson2Tokenizer](https://github.com/sdeleuze/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/http/codec/json/Jackson2Tokenizer.java).

Answer (score 4):

You can use `JsonParser` to get individual events/tokens (which is what `ObjectMapper` uses internally), and this allows more granular access. But all current functionality uses blocking IO, so there is no way to so-called non-blocking (aka "async") parsing.

EDIT: 2019-09-18 -- correction: Jackson 2.9 (https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson/wiki/Jackson-Release-2.9) added support for non-blocking/async JSON parsing (issue https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core/issues/57)

Comment: Thanks, but I am indeed looking for the async way of doing things.. I managed to find a workaround and added my own answer.

Comment: Yes, was about to mention that external framing with length-prefix is probably the way to go... but figured you probably knew about that possibility already.

Comment: I was first going with doing it via jackson directly, but when saw that it only implements blocking IO, I started considering other options.

Comment: Blocking IO is the way to go -- none of Java JSON parsers I know of support push-style parsing. And very few others (for XML, Aalto does). Non-blocking is a major PITA, and I say this after writing a few things. NIO is painful to use, but beyond that, things get very complicated when combining things like compression, auth etc.

Comment: I found that Netty makes NIO a lot less painful, but I agree, it's not always the right way to go, and with authentication I use blocking IO, but for the usual stream I need to implement NIO just performs way better.

Comment: I am curious to know the use case(s) where NIO does perform better. Are you just making copies between file/sockets or something different? There are uses for NIO (massively concurrent things etc), but haven't yet seen cases where throuhgput would benefit.

Comment: I'm working on a massive multi-client which suppose to handle a large amount of (outgoing) requests. From what I've been reading so far if the application has a large amount of IO operations, NIO performs better, and it only make sense since threads are "expensive" and the NIO is "closer" to the OS, am I wrong?

Comment: It is true that NIO can scale to more concurrent connections, as there's no one-thread-per-conn requirement -- but that depends on how costly threads are; over time threads have become much cheaper. NIO is not really faster (AFAIK) on individual connection basis, except if one can use native `ByteBuffer` instances. If copies are made to `byte[]`, NIO is typically slower, since `ByteBuffer` is pretty bad abstraction (google for opinions on that, I don't want to rant more :) ). I think NIO has been disappointing for many use cases that's all.

Comment: So you're saying that converting from `ByteBuffer` into `byte[]` (or in my case `ByteBuffer.toString()`) will slow things down and hurt the performance I'm looking for? Thanks, I'll look into that.

Comment: Yup; or have no impact. For String, one most go to char[] first anyway (via Charset decoder), then construct String.

Answer (score 4):

(I know this thread is old, but since there is no accepted answer, I wanted to add mine, just in case anyone still reads this).

I just published a new library called Actson (https://github.com/michel-kraemer/actson). It works almost like the OP suggested. You can feed it with bytes until it returns one or more JSON events. When it has consumed all input data, you feed it with more bytes and get the next JSON events. This process continues until the JSON text has been fully consumed.

If you know Aalto XML (https://github.com/FasterXML/aalto-xml) then you should be able to familiarise yourself with Actson quickly because the interface is almost the same.

Here's a quick example:

```
// JSON text to parse
byte[] json = "{\"name\":\"Elvis\"}".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

JsonParser parser = new JsonParser(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

int pos = 0; // position in the input JSON text
int event; // event returned by the parser
do {
    // feed the parser until it returns a new event
    while ((event = parser.nextEvent()) == JsonEvent.NEED_MORE_INPUT) {
        // provide the parser with more input
        pos += parser.getFeeder().feed(json, pos, json.length - pos);

        // indicate end of input to the parser
        if (pos == json.length) {
            parser.getFeeder().done();
        }
    }

    // handle event
    System.out.println("JSON event: " + event);
    if (event == JsonEvent.ERROR) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Syntax error in JSON text");
    }
} while (event != JsonEvent.EOF);
```

Answer (score 3):

This is not the answer to my question, but more of a workaround I came up with.

Instead of dealing with the non-blocking IO on the Jackson side of things, I implemented it in my protocol.
All json messages when sent are padded with a 4 bytes int which holds the length of the rest of the message.
To read a json message now becomes easy, I just find out what the length is, read it asynchronously and then can use Jackson with the resulted string.

If anyone does know how this can be done straight from Jackson, I'm still interested to know.

Answer (score 1):

I found some working solution for this problem. You can you use method `inputStream.available` to check if there are some bytes in stream and this method is also non-blocking. So, you can use this method to check if there is something when yes - parse value, if not - wait some time to check again. Two examples are shown below.

Safe style - with checking for START_OBJECT json token:

```
while (run.get()) { 
    if (inputStream.available() > 0) {
        for (JsonToken jsonToken; (null != (jsonToken = jsonParser.nextToken())); ) {
            if (JsonToken.START_OBJECT.equals(jsonToken)) {
                outputStream.onNext(jsonParser.readValueAs(tClass));
                break;
            }
        }
    } else {
        Thread.sleep(200); // Or can be another checking time.
    }
}
```

Or simpliest style:

```
while (run.get()) {
    if (inputStream.available() > 0) {
        outputStream.onNext(jsonParser.readValueAs(tClass));
    } else {
        Thread.sleep(200); // Or can be another checking time.
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have a reader, not an input stream, reader.ready() works.  A variant of your approach worked great for me, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What about to use [Gson](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.6)?

```
private fun handleActions(webSocketMessage: WebSocketMessage, webSocketSession: WebSocketSession): Mono<WebSocketMessage> {
    val action = Gson().fromJson(webSocketMessage.payloadAsText, ActionWs::class.java)
    return when (action.action) {
        "REGISTER" -> companyService.createCompany(action.company)
            .map { webSocketSession.textMessage(jacksonObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(it)) }
        else -> Mono.just(webSocketSession.textMessage(Gson().toJson(CompanyInfo(0, 0, 0, "ACAO INVALIDA!"))))
    }
}
```